# Heuristics for creating an index with specific key length?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, indexing, rails-models

I just learned that it's possible with some databases to specify an index length, which if I understand correctly, indexes just the first *n* characters in a field.

When should you specify an index prefix length? What's a good length?

I'm using PostgreSQL in Rails, but this info should be general enough to apply to other DBMS.

According to http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index

```
add_index(:accounts, :name, name: 'by_name', length: 10)
```

generates:

```
CREATE INDEX by_name ON accounts(name(10))
```

Unfortunately that page doesn't say anything else about index length.

Comment: That create index statement is invalid for Postgres (actually I think MySQL is the only DBMS that supports such a syntax)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think you're right. I should have mentioned that the generated syntax in the example is for MySQL. I imagine Postgres does support index length since [this page](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index) only has a note about SQLite not supporting it, but so far I haven't found anything to confirm that.

Comment: In Postgres you would need to create a function based index: `CREATE INDEX by_name ON accounts(left(name,10))`. But that will only be used if you also used a `where left(name,10) = ...` in your queries. Why do you think you need something like that? This is usually not needed unless you have some _very_ specific problems.

Comment: _"Why do you think you need something like that?"_ That's part of the original question - I'm not entirely sure when it would be needed. Please consider adding an answer if you can offer some insight.

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQL page on CREATE INDEX syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) gives a lot more information.

> Indexes can be created that use only the leading part of column values.

Using a similar example as the one above:

> If names in the column usually differ in the first 10 characters, this index should not be much slower than an index created from the entire `name` column.

The wording is a bit confusing, but I think it's saying that if you specify an index prefix length of 10, and the first 10 characters are usually enough to be unique, then this shorter index could be slower than a full-length index but if it is then not by much.

I don't think that's what they meant to say with "this index should not be much slower", but that's what it says. I would imagine that it's faster since it's operating on less characters, but not much faster.

Some more useful information:

> Also, using column prefixes for indexes can make the index file much smaller, which could save a lot of disk space and might also speed up `INSERT` operations.

So you'll likely have a smaller index file and faster INSERTs.

> A `UNIQUE` index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be distinct. [...] If you specify a prefix value for a column in a `UNIQUE` index, the column values must be unique within the prefix.

You should only specify an index length for a unique index if you can guarantee that the values within the prefix are unique.

As for what's a good length... that's difficult to answer, perhaps someone else can also chime in. I think a short enough length to get the benefits of a smaller index file size and faster operations, but long enough that there's a high chance of the values within the prefix being unique (or guaranteed to be unique if you also use a unique index).

Comment: We really should support this in PostgreSQL. This is *not* the same on PostgreSQL.